# cannot create maven project in STS

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm new to Java EE development and I heard that If I have to learn the Java EE then the Spring MVC is best choice to learn and get Command of.
After downloading STS 3.6 bundle I'm having some troubles/issues in creating Maven Project. My STEPS are

1- Create new project

[image]

2- Error Dialog

[image]

Comment: I cannot update Spring tool Suite Bundle as well :-(

Comment: It looks like STS is being blocked from accessing the Internet by your computer's firewall.

Comment: That's a good point, if you need to use a proxy you can open the network options from STS by going to Window -> Preferences and search for "Proxy"

Comment: Can you run `mvn -version` from the command line?  Do you have your `M2_HOME` environment variable set?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you either don't have Maven installed, or your IDE is not aware of the installation.  For the former problem, have a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/).  For the latter problem, view this page for IDE you are using:

- [Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)

Comment: The IDE he's using is Spring Tool Suite which is a version of Eclipse.

Comment: (Off-topic) Hey Community! Please have respect for senior users! who ever down voted this answer could have edited this answer as well! then why down vote?????

Comment: @ArshadAli Because I don't have time to edit every incorrect answer, especially on my phone, and the answer (1) didn't pay attention to the information given and (2) apparently doesn't realize Maven is included in m2e.

Comment: @chrylis OK I agree & have nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to recommend to get started with Spring using the Spring Tool Suite by using Spring Boot and the guides at http://spring.io/guides. You can import those guides directly into STS and start from there.

Answer (score 0):

I also face with this thing too, but I found a solution that just update Maven project by right click on project -> Maven-> Update Project... or (Alt+F5) then check on force to update as image below :

[image: Figure1 Update Maven project]

It works perfect for me.

NOTE** internet connection is required

Answer (score 0):

I have created project using Spring Tool Suite IDE, with below navigation.

New -> Spring Starter Project

But outcome was always simple maven M2 project with error symbol.

After project build completion I have updated maven project with option "Force Update of Snapshots/Release".

It turned my project M2 project into M2S Project

Thanks